# How to use beforeRouteEnter in setup hook?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How to use `beforeRouteEnter` in `setup` hook?

There is no any mention of `onBeforeRouteEnter` hook in [the documentation](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard). There are only two hooks documented [`onBeforeRouteLeave`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#onbeforerouteleave) and [`onBeforeRouteUpdate`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#onbeforerouteupdate).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the composition API, the timing of `setup` roughly equates to `created` in Vue 2.  By that time, the routing has already occurred, so there would be no meaning to a `beforeRouteEnter` inside of `setup`.

You can use `beforeRouteEnter` alongside `setup`:

```js
setup() {
  console.log('SETUP')
},
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  // Do something
  next({ path: '/foo' }); // Go somewhere else if necessary
  next();                 // Or stay here
}
```

Or you may prefer to put your code in the router config instead, using [`beforeEnter`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) (affects a single route) or [`beforeEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) (affects all routes)

Comment: But what should I do when I need to get the data and if I encounter the error stay on the old page?

Comment: I know it. But how to pass data to [setup](https://pastebin.com/xkzJZThp)? That's why I need the hook `onBeforeRouteEnter`, cause I can retrieve data from it by using closure.

Comment: But it looks like a workaround. That data is not global at all.

Comment: But actually [I can pass the data](https://pastebin.com/9WQG5wXV) from `beforeRouteEnter`. Is it workaround? What's the another way to load data before the displaying of page?

Comment: As I explained, `setup` cannot access the instance because it doesn't exist yet.  You can't do what you're asking.  Here are the 5 alternatives I already listed:  1.  `beforeRouteEnter` + Vuex, 2. `beforeEnter` + Vuex, 3. `beforeEach` + Vuex, 4. Fetch the data in `setup` after `beforeRouteEnter` routing is validated, 5. Use the options api

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand why do you say that `setup` doesn't have access to the instance? There is `getCurrentInstance` method that literally get the current instance.

Comment: That's the *internal* instance, not the component instance you'd get with `console.log(this)`.  That internal instance has no access to `data` until after `setup` is completed.  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/f62rjd3s

Comment: Thanks for clarify. Do you know where I can read about the difference between the internal instance and the component instance?

Comment: I would recommend studying the objects in the console.  The only reading I'm aware of is in the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance)

Comment: What a pity. Thank you, anyway!